# How to make sure the transaction is not included in uncle block

Tags: confirmations, uncle-blocks

If a transaction is included in the uncle block, neither the sender would be deducted nor the receiver would gain, is that right?

Most clients or platforms use `12 confirmations`, how would this makes sense? From my understanding, confirmation is the latest block height number minus transaction block height. Then as the main chain grows, the confirmation would eventually reach 12, is that right? For example, the uncle block height is 10000, the main block height would eventually be above 10012.